# fresco can't load image in disk again in second activity

Tags: android, fresco

I have two activities(A and B). The first activity (A) can show a thumbnail image(ImageC) using fresco. I want to show a full image(ImageC) if user clicks the thumbnail. So I made a second activity(B) to show the same image but full size.

Unfortunately, nothing has been shown in activity B. But if I load another image from activity B, it works fine.

I'm curious, why I can't show the same image on activity B?

Comment: Have you tried any codes ?

Comment: You should be able to. Can you provide code snippets?